# Disable item from spinner when it selected

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-spinner

I am populate spinner data from MySQL
[table 1, table 2, table 3.....so on] but now I want when I select any position or table it will disable from the spinner list

```
adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item_layout,R.id.txt,listItems);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);



     sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String SelectedItem=sp.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

           // String SelectedItem=sp.getSelectedItem().toString();
             if(id==0){

             }else {
                 Intent intent = new Intent();
                 intent.putExtra("spinnerData", SelectedItem);
                 intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);


             }

         }
```

Comment: One solution is to create a custom adapter.